# Dealing with water between concrete basement floor and wood 2x4 framing

Tags: repair, basement, water-damage

New homeowner here, just had our first sewer drain backup.
There is a wall separating the finished part of our basement from the unfinished part.
The wall rests on a 2x4 on top of the concrete basement floor.

During the flood, water got under the 2x4 and appears to have penetrated it at least a little. You can see the water stain coming up around the nail hole in the picture.

[image]

Question: Will this dry out on its own, or should I take some action in order to dry it out? Not really sure how I would get water out from under there.

Thanks a bunch for any advice.

Comment: Besides taking it down, a couple of fans running for a few days is about best you can do.

Comment: Get a dehumidifier and run it around the clock. I may spread some powdered lime on the floor along the 2x4 to help absorb the water. Clean up the moist lime as soon as you can then spread more until it stays dry.

Comment: As noted above, movement of air and removing moisture from air are easiest and best for getting it dry. At a glance, that doesn't look like pressure treated wood for the base, it should be for this reason, but oh well! Be sure to address whatever caused the issue and take any steps necessary to keep it dry in the future

Comment: I would recommend that before you go any farther with any additional work to improve the basement, that you correct the sewer back-up problem first. Sanitary sewers do not just back-up unless there is a downstream piping problem. I would call a plumber that has a snake with an attached camera to check for problems in the sewer piping.